# break doesn't work on pressing enter as input c++

Tags: c++

I wanted to make the code break on entering the first input in the array but it doesn't work when i press enter key, which means that the program doesn't consider enter as an input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
char comet[6]={'0'};
char group[6]={'0'};
int main()
{
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    cin>>comet[i];
    break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can get some information how text formatted input works with `std::cin` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2)

Comment: That is because you input nothing, press a keyboard key such as 'a' or '3' before you hit enter

Comment: i want to break on pressing enter what should i do ?

Comment: @user: Pressing enter inputs a `\n` (and possibly a `\r`).

Comment: i made if statement to make it break on pressing enter but nothing happened , if(comer[i]=='\n')break;

Answer (score 1):

You can use cin.get() function
like so

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  comet[i] = cin.get();
  if(comet[i]=='\n')
  break; 
}
```

I would also advise using Vector its better